# Можно ли так цитировать?

Tags: цитирование

На два похожих вопроса Грамота отвечает по-разному:

1) Толстой писал, что "если тебе мешают люди, то тебе жить незачем. Уходить от людей - это самоубийство".

Можно ли так цитировать? 
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Цитата оформлена верно.

2) Когда прямая речь – не самостоятельное предложение, можно ли внутри нее ставить точку и начинать новое 
предложение? Он сказал, что «это неправильно. (С)ледует исправить так…»
J7
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Лучше перестроить цитату так, чтобы она представляла собой синтаксически самостоятельную конструкцию. Например:

Он сказал, что это неправильно: "Следует...".

Как же будет правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Да нет, совсем не по-разному.
"Лучше перестроить" - совершенно не значит обязательно.
И лучше здесь, видимо, не с пунктуационных позиций, просто нагляднее.

Да и первый вопрос не акцентирует внимания на точку внутри кавычек.

По сути. Я не знаю правила, которое ограничивало бы как-то текст внутри цитаты. Только естественными соображениями разумной длины и воспринимаемости.

*На всякий случай. Реально противоречивые ответы у "Справки" бывают, да. Отвечают разные люди, далеко не всегда достаточно информированные.*

Answer (score 1):

Толстой писал, что "если тебе мешают люди, то тебе жить незачем. Уходить от людей - это самоубийство".

Хотя явных рекомендаций для подобного оформления цитат нет, всё-таки можно сказать, что **смотрится предложенный вариант неестественно** (а если цитата будет состоять из трех-четырех предложений!).  С точки зрения грамматики,  такая конструкция является  СПП, в котором первое предложение цитаты является придаточным изъяснительным   с союзом ЧТО,  второе же предложение связано с СПП только кавычками.

И главное, в таком оформлении **нет необходимости**, так как можно записать цитату в виде прямой речи: "Толстой писал: "Если тебе мешают люди, то тебе жить незачем. Уходить от людей - это самоубийство".  Или с многоточием, если цитата не с начала: "Толстой писал: "...если тебе мешают люди, то тебе жить незачем. Уходить от людей - это самоубийство".

**Пример оформления:** М. А. Булгаков в романе «Мастер и Маргарита» говорил: «Никогда и ничего не просите! Никогда и ничего, и в особенности у тех, кто сильнее вас. Сами предложат и сами все дадут!»